# how to pass value at runtime in url in android using json parsing?

Tags: android, json, url

i am trying to  get name and address of hospitals,atm's,restaurants ....etc. near by my location with the help of google near by places api so i use json parsing ,since i can able to get all the name and address but only problem is that i can't understand that how can i get different values of ex. hotel,hospital,atm,bank...etc. using same url by putting different different values in run time.here is my url ....

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=26.841,75.801&radius=5000&types=hospital&key=AIzaSyBstND0mA7NZJPulZRcNtoWyJwXaKxqsFI";

In the above url there is a field "types" ,here i want to pass different different values at run time.....like hotel,hospital,bank,atm ...etc.

Comment: You want to change the **type** at run time. is that it??

Answer (score 0):

```
String type = "hospital";
int radius =5000;
String string = String.format("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch
       /json?location=26.841,75.801&radius=%d&types=%s&
       key=AIzaSyBstND0mA7NZJPulZRcNtoWyJwXaKxqsFI", radius, type);
```

Comment: thanks.....thank you so much.....your solution is so valuable for me...God bless you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Uri to build this

```
String  base="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=26.841,75.801";
String RADIUS="5000";
String TYPES="hospital";
String KEYS="AIzaSyBstND0mA7NZJPulZRcNtoWyJwXaKxqsFI";

Uri builtUri=Uri.parse(base).buildUpon()
         .appendQueryParameter("radius",RADIUS)
         .appendQueryParameter("types",TYPES)
         .appendQueryParameter("key",KEYS)
         .build();
URL url=new URL(builtUri.toString());
```

**OUTPUT**

> https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=26.841,75.801&radius=5000&types=hospital&key=AIzaSyBstND0mA7NZJPulZRcNtoWyJwXaKxqsFI

You can easily change value of RADIUS,TYPES on runtime